# How to remove border on input while being active

Tags: html, css

Currently studying a little bit of simple coding for school. I tried copying the Twitter UI but how do I remove the border on the input element while typing?
[Here's what it's look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPt4A.png)

[And here's what it's look like while typing in it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPyVn.png)

Here is my code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      .twitter-dp {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        object-fit: cover;
        border-radius: 25px;
        vertical-align: middle;
        margin-right: 5px;
      }

      .text {
        font-size: 17px;
        border: none;
        width: 300px;
        vertical-align: middle;
      }

      .tweet {
        vertical-align: middle;
        background-color: rgb(74, 171, 240);
        border-style: none;
        font-style: arial;
        font-size: 17px;
        color: white;
        padding-top: 5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        border-radius: 25px;
        cursor: pointer;
      }

      .tweet:hover {
        opacity: 0.8;
      }

      input {
        border: none;
        background-color: transparent;
        resize: none;
        outline: none;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <img class="twitter-dp" src="practiceimage.jpg" />
    <input class="text" type="text" placeholder="What's happening?" />
    <button class="tweet">Tweet</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say for sure without seeing the html codes, but you can try to add these codes between style tags.

```
input {
    border: none;
    background-color: transparent;
    resize: none;
    outline: none;
}
```